# When I click on search view the list view appear on the my layout and the layout design in the scrollview in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview

When I click on search view the list view appear on my layout and the layout design in the scrollview in Android Studio.

What should I do to make it so that list view run on the scrollview layout? (I am working in Java)

[image: app]

Answer (score 0):

**On Recyclerview XML**
Add this line

```
android:translationZ="10dp"
```